# Use meta_query to get title of associated post

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I have two post types that I've associated in one direction by assigning Post A as a custom meta field of Post B. I need to search based on the titles of Post A and return the associated Post B results. This feels a little tricky.

Normally I can display titles from Post A like so:

```
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author_post_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_author', true);
        $post_object = get_post( $author_post_id );
        echo get_the_title($post_object);
```

And I believe I'm using `meta_query` correctly to search Post B:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'journal_entry',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'custom_author',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
         );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            // Loop
        endwhile; endif;
        // Reset post data
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

But I think I need to shoehorn `get_the_title` into my `meta_query` value. I think. I'm a little turned around. Am I on the correct path?

Comment: You should use `the_*` functions before `get_the_*` functions. Later normally (ok, sometimes) don't have filters attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `$title_search = get_the_title($post_object);` and then using it in your query as `'value' => $title_search`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'journal_entry',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'custom_author',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => $title_search
        )
    )
 );
```

Comment: stealthyninja, your suggestion appears to work. Something must be wrong with my loop though. I'm using the suggestion as-is, yielding nothing, where my loop contains `the_title` and `the_content`.

However, doing `print_r` before `WP_Query` yields: `Array ( [post_type] => journal_entry [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => custom_author [compare] => LIKE [value] => Sandso Person ) ) )`, which appears to be entirely correct.

Comment: Actually I think I'm going about this completely the wrong way. I cobbled together code to query a single post when I want to query all `journal_entry` posts.

stealthyninja's solution works for a most recent entry, so I'm marking it correct.